# Delay setText in Game

Tags: android, delayed-execution

I tried looking at the other solutions on StackOverFlow, but none seemed to fix my implementation of a game I'm making. I need it to delay each iteration of playGame method(which sets the TextView among other things) for 3 or so seconds without delaying the whole thing in a while loop.

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    int count = 0;
    while(!stopGuessing){
        Log.i("count", Integer.toString(count));
        if (count > 9) {
            break;
        }
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Do something after 5s = 5000ms
               playGame();

            }
        }, 5000);
        //playGame();
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to wait 5 sec after your app resumes, before playing the game? If you are waiting for some other process to complete then you should actually check that process is complete rather than waiting an arbitrary length of time.

Comment: I'm am trying to make it look like the computer is taking time to "guess" if the user entered the password correctly each time. Ideally 3 second intervals between each computer guess. This guessing occurs in the playGame method.